# Securing web api using random session number

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, rest, asp.net-web-api

I am making a web API/Rest API in MVC where each API takes one parameter called `user_session`

So when a user logs in, I generate a 10 digit session and pass it back to user which needs to be given as input for any subsequent API calls.

Here's what my typical code looks like:

```
$.ajax({
   url: '@Url.Action("GetUserDetail", "myapi")',
         type: "GET",
        data: { UserID: '@user.user_id', SessionID: '@user_session' },
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (response) {
        }
})
```

My question is, is this the right approach or is there a better way of doing it? Is it secure?

Answer (score 0):

You can very well use the [HTTP Cookies](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies) for remembering the session instead of manually passing it as a param for every request.

I’ll give very short explanation on this topic.

1. Server sets a cookie when a user logs-in.
2. This cookie will be sent to all the api calls as it is defined as a HTTP cookie.
3. Server can validate or know about the session using this cookie value in header of the request.